# Random walk based on uniform distribution

Tags: plotting, random

```
uniformm = UniformDistribution[{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]; 
dist = PDF[uniformm, {x, y}]; 
Plot3D[dist, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Filling -> Axis]
c2 = Accumulate @ Prepend[RandomVariate[uniformm, {500, 2}], {0, 0}];
ListLinePlot[c2, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

I am trying to plot a random walk drawn from a flat distribution.
However, I keep getting x and y axes without a random walk graph.

Comment: RandomVariate[uniformm, {500, 2}] should read RandomVariate[uniformm, 500]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c2 = Accumulate @ Prepend[RandomVariate[uniformm, 500], {0, 0}];


ListLinePlot[c2, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: compare `RandomVariate[uniformm, 3]` versus `RandomVariate[uniformm, {3, 2}]` to see why  you need `RandomVariate[uniformm,500]`  not `RandomVariate[uniformm, {500,2}]`