# Random Walk under a Uniform Distribution

Tags: random

```
uniformm = UniformDistribution[{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]; dist = 
 PDF[uniformm, {x, y}]; Plot3D[dist, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 Filling -> Axis]
c2 = Accumulate@Prepend[RandomVariate[uniformm, {500, 2}], {0, 0}];
ListLinePlot[c2, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

I am trying to plot a random walk drawn from a flat distribution (x and y fall within [-1,1]).
However, I keep getting x and y axes without a random walk graph.

Thank you

Comment: This seems to be the same question as here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238838/flat-distribution-for-random-walk Edit you question there or request clarification from the answerers if you have issues

Answer (score 1):

Everything's basically right here! You simply have an extra dimension in your random walk.

`uniformm = UniformDistribution[{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]` here is a uniform distribution in 2D, and produces lists of length 2. However, `RandomVariate[uniformm, {500, 2}]` produces a 500 by 2 array of samples from that distribution. Since each sample has length 2, `RandomVariate[uniformm, {500, 2}]` is an array with dimensions 500 x 2 x 2.

So, change `RandomVariate[uniformm, {500, 2}]` to `RandomVariate[uniformm, 500]` and you should be good. :)